# Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Whenever I tried to create a event, after clicking on create it says:

> Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters: id

I had tried by doing `$model->save(false);` but when I do so, it only uploads the text, and not the images.

My eventController code is:

```
     public function actionCreate()
        {
        $model = new Events();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            // get the instance of the uploaded file 
            $imageUpload = $model ->event_name;
            $model->file =UploadedFIle::getInstance($model,'file'); 
            if($model->file) {
        $model->event_image='images/'.$imageUpload.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();
        $model->file->saveAs( 'images/'.$imageUpload.'.'.$model->file->extension );
} else {
    $model->save();
}




            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->event_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your form action? Is it pointing to create action?

Comment: thank u guys !! i found my error and solved it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `'id' => $model->event_id` is looking for `lastInsertID`

Try this

```
if($model->save())
{
    $lastInsertID = $model->getPrimaryKey();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $lastInsertID]);
}
else
{
    // print_r($model->getErrors()); => check whether any validation errors are there
}
```

Also your can try to make the fields as `safe` in model rules.

```
[['field1','field2','field3'], 'safe'],
```

Finally, you can try to check after `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`, if the model has attributes set or not by 
`print_r($model->attributes);` before `save(false)`

Comment: Glad to hear that, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you